# SQL | Calculate time difference between 2 rows

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am looking for a way to get the timestamp between the first and the next row with a timestamp on. The idea of the table is to log how much time a light has been switch on for.

The layout I currently have is...

```
| id | light_id | timestamp         | log_type_id |
___________________________________________________
|  1 |        1 | current_timestamp |           1 |
|  2 |        4 | current_timestamp |           1 |
|  3 |        1 | current_timestamp |           2 |
|  4 |        1 | current_timestamp |           1 |
```

So the idea here is I'd be able calculate the time between ID 1 and 3, and then 4 and the next one that comes along with the same light_id. I don't know if this is the best way to do this kind of logging and I am open to opinions if people have a better solution :).

`log_type_id 1 = on`
`log_type_id 2 = off`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's a good way to do it, but in MySQL you'll need to wait for MySQL 8.0 for the lead() and lag() analytic functions, though it's still doable without access to analytic functions.

Here are two examples of doing it the old school way, the first is more traditional:

```
select t1.id, t1.light_id, t1.timestamp, t1.log_type_id
     , l1.timestamp Prior_Timstamp
     , timestampdiff(second, l1.timestamp, t1.timestamp) minutes
  from YourData t1
  left join YourData l1
    on l1.id = (select max(id) from YourData m1 
                 where m1.id < t1.id
                   and m1.light_id = t1.light_id);
```

And this second uses the LIMIT/OFFSET clauses which can allow you to look further back by increasing the offset:

```
select t1.id, t1.light_id, t1.timestamp, t1.log_type_id
     , l1.timestamp Prior_Timestamp
     , timestampdiff(second, l1.timestamp, t1.timestamp) minutes
  from YourData t1
  left join YourData l1
    on l1.id = (select id from YourData m1 
                 where m1.id < t1.id
                   and m1.light_id = t1.light_id
                 order by id desc limit 1 offset 0);
```

To look forward (lead) just change inequality from < to >, and the aggregate in the first query from max to min or the order by from desc to asc in the second query.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7929e3/1) demonstrating the code (unburied from comments at @Strawberry's request).

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by the t1 and l1? Is it referring to the same table?

Comment: I've done this but it brings back all of the rows rather than the 2 that are just the closest together?

Comment: The T1, L1, and M1 are just aliases for your table.  Since I'm including it multiple times in the query I need a way to uniquely identify each copy of it, so I give them an alias.  I left out the optional key word AS between the table name and it's alias for brevity.  I've edited my queries to give the output column from L1 a different column name, and to calculate the number of minutes between the two timestamps. You can see it [here SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7929e3/1)

Comment: Don’t bury something as marvellous as a fiddle in the comments